# Gradle Eclipse WTP plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I have, Eclipse multi-project, Gradle based, Tomcat 7

I have WEB app, uses Gradle WTP plugin: eclipse-wtp

I have added compile project dependencies:  compile project(':common')

When I debug, debugger gives ClassNotFoundException exception, so for some reason Tomcat cannot see dependencies from 'common' project.

Any suggestions how I can fix/workaround the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This this is well known issue about WTP plugin, and probably not fixed yet...
It is required that all projects have WPT plugin applied. Gradel script should contain "apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'"

This way Eclipse will correctly transfer dependencies.

Comment: I will try this, apparently there are somebody who understand what I'm talking about

Comment: Thanks man, it works, sorry I didn’t provide enough info, but after 2 days hitting my head on the wall I really think everybody should understand what I say :)
 As for others who down voted me, please give people some slack and maybe ask the question first, instead of showing the arrogance.